Не понимаю как парсить судебные решения
Учувствую в НИР, требуется создать чат-бота, в который пишется запрос с описанием преступления,  проступка и тд., чтобы чат-бот вероятное наказание за это. Необходимо спарсить причину обращения в суд, а также решение этого судебного процесса. Вот пример документа https://sudact.ru/regular/doc/uzc1F9Z1Pxr8/
Подскажите как мне с это сделать? В самом html сайта решение и причина никак не обозначаются.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

вы задание даете? так вам к фрилансерам.

если отвечать на вопрос в заголовке, можно сначала нужно спарсить страницу (https://habr.com/ru/companies/ruvds/articles/796885/), а потом с полученного текста решения регулярным выражением искать информацию, например, после слов решил/решение и т.п. (https://habr.com/ru/articles/349860/). как именно - на это сложно ответить. т.к. после этого ещё и в тексте решения нужно вытащить назначенное наказание

но по сути вопроса не совсем понятна логика работы бота - каким образом будет бот выходить на требуемое решение? если просто по статье первое попавшееся, то тогда это не совсем "вероятное наказание". я бы попробовал найти статистику назначения наказаний по статьям УК. здесь https://stat.апи-пресс.рф/stats/ug/t/14/s/17 есть статистика по видам наказаний. можно было бы выкачать базу себе и уже можно было бы по запросу в бота выдавать наиболее вероятный вид наказания. если найти такую же статистику, но уже по размерам, то вопрос бы полностью закрылся

Ох уж опять эти любители позакрывать все подряд... Господа закрывающие, человек спрашивает как "в однородном" тексте найти нужные данные для дальнейшей работы. И чего тут вы хотите конкретизировать? Человек даже написал для чего ему это надо, но нет "фриланс", "конкретизируй!"... Автор, вы ведь метку ML поставили, вот собственно ML и просите решить данную задачу) К примеру вот, написал простую прогу (код не дам, ибо C#), которая берет с сайта текст и отдает его в локальную модель (Phi4 запущенную через Ollama) с нужным промтом, ну и вот все нужные данные.
